# In ZK, in my GenericForwardComposer class, how can I capture all onClick and onChange events?

Tags: java, ajax, zk

I know that I can capture a specific button or text field if I define an onClick$id method with a matching id. I'd like to have a generic onClick-something and onChange-something method that gets called when any button is clicked or any text field is updated. Is that possible with the ZK framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways.

1) Define a single event handler on the controller and forward all other component events to that event handler. For eg. consider this sample ZUML file that has 3 Button components

```
<zk>
<window id="mainwin" border="normal" title="hello" apply="pkg.TestComposer">
    <button id="btn1" label="Click Me 1" forward="mainwin.onClick" />
    <button id="btn2" label="Click Me 2" forward="mainwin.onClick" />
    <button id="btn3" label="Click Me 3" forward="mainwin.onClick" />
</window>
</zk>
```

Now in the controller applied to the Window component containing these 3 Button components you cab define a single onClick event handler as below

```
public void onClick () throws Exception {
    Messagebox.show("Someone clicked!!!");
}
```

Now for each Button you can use a forward attribute and define the target component as well as the event to be handled in following format forward="event-name=target-component.target-event". For more details refer to forward attribute reference [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/ZUML/Attributes/forward).

2) In ZK 6 there is even more elegant way to achieve this using SelectorComposer and annotations to define event handlers. For e.g.

```
@Listen("onClick = window > button") 
public void onClickAnyButton() {
  // ...    
}
```

Please refer to [this smalltalk](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/January/Envisage_ZK_6%3a_An_Annotation_Based_Composer_For_MVC) for more details on SelectorComposer